# Making a counter app - Do I have to do something after saving to Core Data?

Tags: swift, core-data, increment

Trying my hand in Swift and creating my first "app". I'm essentially creating a cookie-clicker clone where you just click an image in the center of your screen repeatedly to increment your score.

I'm experiencing some issues where clicking the image once will increment my score by 1, but upon clicking it again, the score stays 1.

I'm almost positive I'm supposed to do something after saving to CoreData - I just don't know what. Do I have to refresh the View? Sorry for the newbie question

```
@IBAction func tapHomeImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Score is the name of my Entity, with "points" being an attribute
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Score", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let score = Score(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    // **As an aside question, is there a more efficient way to code the below? The issue I have is that score.points is of type NSNumber
    let intScore = score.points as Int
    let incrementedIntScore = intScore + 1
    score.points = NSNumber(integer: incrementedIntScore)

    var error: NSError?
    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)

    //homeScoreLabel is an IBOutlet for the Score displayed on the page
    homeScoreLabel?.text = "\(score.points)"
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything **after** saving, you need to do something **before** calling this method. You need to find an instance of `Score` that already exists, and use that.

When you get to this line:

```
let score = Score(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
```

You create a new instance of the `Score` entity, every time this method runs. So when you do this:

```
let intScore = score.points as Int
let incrementedIntScore = intScore + 1
score.points = NSNumber(integer: incrementedIntScore)
```

You're working with a brand new instance every time. The score is initially zero, and you always increase it to 1.

What you should do:

1. Use a single instance of `Score` and save that as a property of your view controller. That is, have something like this:

   ```
   var score: Score?
   ```
2. Assign a value to this property **once**, when the view controller loads. Since you're saving data, you should use `executeFetchRequest` to look up a previously-saved instance. If no previous instance exists, **then** create a new one via `insertIntoManagedObjectContext`.
3. Use that instance in this `IBAction`.

There are other ways to fix the code. The key is to make sure that you use the same instance of `Score` every time instead of creating a new one at every tap.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It definitely makes sense why my function is doing this now. I do have a question around this sentence you wrote: "you should use executeFetchRequest to look up a previously-saved instance." What exactly does that mean?

Comment: That method is how you find and load data that you have previously saved with Core Data. What I mean is that once you save an instance of `Score`, you should load it the next time the app launches.

Comment: Sorry - I was not clear. I have an executeFetchRequest method in my viewDidLoad function. However, I was under the impression it returned an array of objects. I guess my question is: "How do I use that method to bring up the same instance of Score() that I can use to call something like score.points?"